# Хранение ключей extra

Tags: android, android-fragment

В моем проекте у меня есть потребность в передаче некоторых данных в fragment. Я сделал это с помощью bundle. В intent записываются некоторые значения которые определяют поведение фрагмента.
Выглядит это примерно так:

```
Fragment fragment = SomeFragment()
Bundle bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(key, value)
fragment.arguments = bundle
```

Внутри SomeFragment идет проверка на value и в зависимости от того проходит она или нет выбирается нужное поведение fragment. 
Все работает, но пара вещей не дают мне покоя:

1. Где хранить key что бы не копировать его руками? Если ли общие решения для этого.
2. Стоит ли совмещать два очень похожих между собой поведения в одном фрагменте? (Хорошим примером будет отображение списка \ отображение избранного из этого списка)

Comment: Можете пояснить 1 вопрос?

Comment: Внутри fragment нужно будет проверять если ли значение по ключу, для этого нужно знать ключ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Может я не совсем понял вопрос. Поправьте, если не прав. Для такого обычно используем какой-нибудь класс с константами:

```
public class BunldeConstants{
   public static final String MY_KEY = "super_key";
}
```

И используем потом:

```
Fragment fragment = SomeFragment();
Bundle bundle = Bundle();
bundle.putString(BunldeConstants.MY_KEY, value);
```

2) Лично я стараюсь по максимуму переиспользовать код. Если у вас список в чём-то вроде `ListView` отображается, то там есть возможность задать `Filter`. Я бы предложил передавать какое-то условие для этого фильтра с помощью `Bundle`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я сомневался в правильности класса с константами, но раз это принятая практика то почему бы и нет.

Comment: @nekaneka можно ещё `enum`'ы использовать.